# Movie as a plane does not update every frame, only the first frame is rendered

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I need to import videoclip as a plane on Blender. I tried with Blender (2.79, 2.83.5) versions.
I can see movie on preview but not when render.
When render with cycle engine, only first frame is render and movie don't play but freeze first frame.

When render with eevee image is purple.

I have tried video import as a plane in blank "general" project.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot

EDIT: [project source](https://easyupload.io/8bt1ui)

Comment: Hi there : ) Can you share your .blend file with packed in textures also add the image of the node setup of the material of the plane. For rendering animations you need to click on *Render > Render Animations*.  I guess you pressed Render Image.

Comment: https://easyupload.io/8bt1ui project

Comment: I have taken a look at your file. It renders quite fine in my PC. How did u render it ? Did u press *Render > Render Image or press F12* ?

Comment: I press "render animation". I want to export video and some 3d object that is not in project

Comment: I forgot to say...You need to go to the *output tab > Output > File Format* and select a video format like .Avi or FFmpeg . It is PNG by default and I guess you are using it. That is precisely why you are not getting a video instead a photo. If this helps I will post it as the answer.

Comment: Nxdhin2005, Sorry but I don't have problem with output (image or video) format. My problem is that cycle render engine draw First frame and than freeze it until video ended

Comment: Apparently it is a known bug. Devs fixes issue in 2.9